How to modify the behaviour of the Writter plain via a lua-filter
Has the -t plain option has its own Writer ? , If so haven't seen such in the source code https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/tree/main/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers (no plain.hs or something similar)
Regardless of that , I want to create some Custom Objects for my own Syntax, or some similar functionality. My syntax is similar to plain but some things are refined, that is why I am building it up on top of plain using filters.
For building new Objects, I am using then the RawBlock pandoc's built in object, which lets you specify an arbitrary string called format as its first Paremeter.
So taking the example of this input03.hs
[ Header
    1
    ( "the-following-should-be-a-rawblock" , [] , [] )
    [ Str "The"
    , Space
    , Str "following"
    , Space
    , Str "should"
    , Space
    , Str "be"
    , Space
    , Str "a"
    , Space
    , Str "RawBlock"
    ]
, RawBlock
    (Format "html")
    "<div class=\"raw-html-block\">\n  This is a raw HTML block.\n</div>"
]

I am doing
pandoc -f native -t plain input03.hs --verbose 
For what I see
[INFO] Not rendering RawBlock (Format "html") "<div class=\"raw-html-block\">\n  This is a raw HTML block.\n</div>"
The following should be a RawBlock

I was just wondering how can I modify the Writer via a Filter?
I had tried unsucessfully
filter01.lua
Writer = pandoc.scaffolding.Writer

Writer.Block.RawBlock = function (rb, opts)
    return { rb.text }
end

But doing pandoc -f native -t plain input03.hs -L filter01.lua --verbose
Doesn't print the RawBlock
Writer = pandoc.scaffolding.Writer

Writer.Block.RawBlock = function (rb, opts)
    return { rb.text }
end

So I have done my own Writer.
writer01.lua
Writer = pandoc.scaffolding.Writer

Writer.Block.Header = function (h, opts)
    return { nil }
end

Writer.Block.RawBlock = function (rb, opts)
    return { rb.text }
end

Which has the expected results
pandoc -f native -t writer01.lua input03.hs --verbose 
<div class="raw-html-block">
  This is a raw HTML block.
</div>

Questions that I have not clear are:

Is there a Writer file in the source code for Plain
Is it possible to slightly modify a Writer via a -L lua-filter ? (looks like is not possible as according to the documentation they act after the Reader , and before the Writer)
If I have to defined my own Writer, how can I handle to return all the Pandoc Objects, may they be parsed by the reader in any of the documents? , shall I define them all to return nil ?


I have came up with a solution handling all the pandoc objects on what I call the writer-boilerplate.lua which may be somehow close to the plain writer behaviour.
Should you ever need to create your Custom Writer , this is a good starting point. If you need to modify the behaviour for any of the Objects, just Cut and paste after the boilerplate such function, with the modified code.
-- WRITER BOILTERPLATE
-----------------------------------------------------------
Writer = pandoc.scaffolding.Writer

-- Generic handler for Blocks
Writer.Block.Generic = function(el)
  return pandoc.write(pandoc.Pandoc({ el }), "plain")
end

-- Assign all Block elements to use the generic handler
Writer.Block.Plain = Writer.Block.Generic
Writer.Block.Para = Writer.Block.Generic
Writer.Block.LineBlock = Writer.Block.Generic
Writer.Block.CodeBlock = Writer.Block.Generic
Writer.Block.RawBlock = Writer.Block.Generic
Writer.Block.BlockQuote = Writer.Block.Generic
Writer.Block.OrderedList = Writer.Block.Generic
Writer.Block.BulletList = Writer.Block.Generic
Writer.Block.DefinitionList = Writer.Block.Generic
Writer.Block.Header = Writer.Block.Generic
Writer.Block.HorizontalRule = Writer.Block.Generic
Writer.Block.Table = Writer.Block.Generic
Writer.Block.Figure = Writer.Block.Generic
Writer.Block.Div = Writer.Block.Generic

-- Generic handler for Inlines
Writer.Inline.Generic = function(el)
  return pandoc.write(pandoc.Pandoc({ pandoc.Para({ el }) }), "plain")
end

-- Assign all Inline elements to use the generic handler
Writer.Inline.Str = Writer.Inline.Generic
Writer.Inline.Emph = Writer.Inline.Generic
Writer.Inline.Underline = Writer.Inline.Generic
Writer.Inline.Strong = Writer.Inline.Generic
Writer.Inline.Strikeout = Writer.Inline.Generic
Writer.Inline.Superscript = Writer.Inline.Generic
Writer.Inline.Subscript = Writer.Inline.Generic
Writer.Inline.SmallCaps = Writer.Inline.Generic
Writer.Inline.Quoted = Writer.Inline.Generic
Writer.Inline.Cite = Writer.Inline.Generic
Writer.Inline.Code = Writer.Inline.Generic
Writer.Inline.Space = function() return " " end
Writer.Inline.SoftBreak = function() return " " end
Writer.Inline.LineBreak = function() return "\n" end
Writer.Inline.Math = Writer.Inline.Generic
Writer.Inline.RawInline = Writer.Inline.Generic
Writer.Inline.Link = Writer.Inline.Generic
Writer.Inline.Image = function(el) return el.src end
Writer.Inline.Note = Writer.Inline.Generic
Writer.Inline.Span = Writer.Inline.Generic

-- Custom exceptions (if needed)
Writer.Inline.Space = function() return " " end
Writer.Inline.SoftBreak = function() return " " end
Writer.Inline.LineBreak = function() return "\n" end

-- EOF EOF EOF WRITER BOILTERPLATE
-----------------------------------------------------------

Knowing this and in order to do our 'Custom' Pandoc Objects we can make use of the following syntax.
I have used this for the Metadata of the html documents.
I create RawBlock with Custom defined formats, that then I will handle in the Writer.
fil_meta_to_rawblock.lua
-- A Pandoc filter to iterate through document metadata and pass it 
-- as RawBlock as rb.format = head-<key>  rb.text=<value>
-- --------------------------------------------------------
meta_list_object = {}
return {
    { Meta = function (meta)
       for key, value in pairs(meta) do
            table.insert(meta_list_object, pandoc.RawBlock('head-' .. key, pandoc.utils.stringify(value)))
       end
    end
    } , { Pandoc = function (doc)
        for _, meta_object in pairs(meta_list_object) do
            table.insert(doc.blocks, 1, meta_object)
        end
        return doc
    end
    }
}
-- --------------------------------------------------------

Then adding to the boiler-plate of the writer the following function
my-custom-writer.lua
-- PARSING METADATA RAWBLOCKS
-- -----------------------------------
Writer.Block.RawBlock = function (rb, opts)
    if string.match(rb.format, 'head-.*') then
        key = string.gsub(rb.format, 'head%-', '')
        return 'head-' .. key .. ': ' .. rb.text
    else
        return rb.text
    end
end
-- -----------------------------------

